# Colorizing a grayscale (but RGB) image with transparency by a background color underneath

Tags: css, html

I have tried some of the basics: Parent div with background color then an image with transparency (think of a circle lets say) higher in the stack order. This will color the image but doesn't seem to work once a child is present. What will work is:

```
 .tinted-image {
 width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background:url("images/testNote.png") rgba(0, 171, 255, 0.5);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.red:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

}
However, that background color is a square; the shape/size of the div. I'm trying to keep the color from appearing anywhere except for the actual image.

Think of a circle with a transparent background; I want to color only the circle. The idea here is to be able to use just one image (the circle) and recolor by css only.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to accomplish, but you may want to look into `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden` on your container (`border-radius` can be used to create a circular element, and setting a hidden `overflow` would prevent anything outside that circle from displaying)

Comment: Well, my actual icon is a music note....so I want to just color the note; not the background of the div or even the 'img' tag because that's always a square even when one has a transparent background.

Comment: I would recommend going to http://jsfiddle.net and creating a demo of your issue to share here, so that people can assess your exact problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about an SVG? You can style its contents with CSS.

HTML (path copy-pasted from [an SVG from Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Music-eighthnote.svg)):

```
<svg>
    <path d="m 40,0 0,74.531249 c -2.19436,-3.1329 -11.11823,-3.60474 -17.375,-0.15625 -7.41543,4.0871 -10.79756,11.75107 -7.5625,17.125 3.23507,5.37393 11.86582,6.43085 19.28125,2.34375 4.45154,-2.45352 7.41871,-6.2048 8.40625,-9.96875 0.45244,-2.06878 0.18854,-3.14209 0.15625,-4.59375 l 0,-52.656249 c 32.53399,8.241492 17.51919,36.811079 14.59268,46.902749 26.72779,-36.505741 -14.22819,-51.395935 -14.59268,-73.527749 z" />
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
svg {
    fill: red;
}
```

In practice, though, you'd probably want to have the SVG in a separate file and use a more practical CSS selector, but I think this works well.

However, judging by your question, I'm not quite sure what you're asking or what you're trying to do. This is the closest thing I could think of, so I could be wrong.

Comment: wow, I've been messing with SVG's but not that exact thing and it works! Thanks